# highcharts on top of google map

Tags: javascript, html, css, highcharts

I am displaying a highchart's polar chart on top of google map to to show the wind direction on the map. 
Please see this example http://jsfiddle.net/rishad/azarpssv/

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Simple Polar chart on Map</title>
        <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1.0">
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <style>
            #wrapper { position: relative; }
            #over_map { position: absolute; top: 75px; left: 75px; z-index: 99; }
        </style>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript">
        $(function () {
            $('#container').highcharts({
                chart: {
                    polar: true,
                    backgroundColor:'rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.0)'
                },
                title: {
                    text: ''
                },
                pane: {
                    startAngle: 0,
                    endAngle: 360
                },
                exporting: { 
                  enabled: false 
                },
                legend: {
                    enabled: false
                },
                xAxis: {
                    tickInterval: 45,
                    min: 0,
                    max: 360,
                    labels: {
                        formatter: function () {
                            return this.value + '°';
                        }
                    }
                },
                yAxis: {
                    min: 0
                },
                plotOptions: {
                    series: {
                        pointStart: 0,
                        pointInterval: 45
                    },
                    column: {
                        pointPadding: 0,
                        groupPadding: 0
                    }
                },
                series: [{
                    type: 'line',
                    name: 'Line 1',
                    data: [8, 7, 6, 5, 4, 3, 2, 1],
                    pointPlacement: 'between'
                }, {
                    type: 'line',
                    name: 'Line 2',
                    data: [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8]
                }, {
                    type: 'line',
                    name: 'Line 3',
                    data: [1, 8, 2, 7, 3, 6, 4, 5]
                }]
            });
        });

        </script>
    </head>
    <body>

        <script src="js/highcharts.js"></script>
        <script src="js/highcharts-more.js"></script>

        <div id="wrapper">
            <div id="map" style="width: 500px; height: 500px;"></div>
            <div id="over_map">
                <div id="container" style="width: 350px; height: 350px;"></div>

            </div>
        </div>

        <script>
          var map;
          function initMap() {
          var myCenter = new google.maps.LatLng (53.244661, -2.479360)
            map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
              center: myCenter,
              zoom: 16,
              draggable:false,
              scrollwheel:false
            });
            var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                position: myCenter,
                map: map,
            });
          }
        </script>
        <script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyCpmEdrvxaqxIIGuawFFtBuhBUQ76Q2hLo&signed_in=true&callback=com/maps/api/js?sensor=false&callback=initMap"></script>

  </body>
</html>
```

But I am unable to make it one element. For instance, I want to put this at the centre of a html table row but that does not work.

```
<table style="width: 100%;">
    <tr align="center">
        <td>
            <div id="wrapper">
                <div id="map" style="width: 500px; height: 500px;"></div>
                <div id="over_map">
                    <div id="container" style="width: 350px; height: 350px;"></div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

If I change the padding, it will not work for different screen size. Can anyone help me with the css.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Could you show example which doesn't work? Also, what do you mean by "one element"? Something like google map and Highcharts chart inside one container?

Comment: well I have put them in one container i.e. `#wrapper` but if I try to put them in table and align the table row to center, the map moves to the center but polar chart does not, that is because of the absolute position in the css. please see the edit

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is caused by incorrect left parameter in the CSS styles. You should avoid to use harcoded value (because in table you have dynamic 100%). So the solution is using `calc(50% - 175px)` where 175px is half of chart width.

CSS:

```
#wrapper { position: relative; }
#over_map { position: absolute; top: 75px; left:calc(50% - 175px); z-index: 99; }
```

Example:
- http://jsfiddle.net/sjmxke8g/

Comment: That worked... didn't think about the calc method :). Thank you